# how to append element to dom with case-sensitive elem name

Tags: javascript, svg

In the following example I have an inline SVG. You can see that within it, some of the SVG elements (`<radialGradient>` and `<linearGradient>`) are camel case. How would I programatically add another such element to the `<defs>` parent.

`document.createElement()` converts its argument to lowercase before creating the node, so the case sensitive element name is lost. And the Square remains white in my rendered SVG.

Is there any way to do this using javascript?

```js
const linearGradient = document.createElement('linearGradient')
linearGradient.id="my-gradient"
linearGradient.setAttribute('x1', '320.38')
linearGradient.setAttribute('y1', '145.87')
linearGradient.setAttribute('x2', '685.45')
linearGradient.setAttribute('y2', '447.31')
linearGradient.setAttribute('gradientUnits','userSpaceOnUse')


 const stop1 = document.createElement('stop')
 stop1.setAttribute('offset', '0')
 stop1.setAttribute('stop-color', '#ed1e79')
 
 
 const stop2 = document.createElement('stop')
 stop2.setAttribute('offset', '1')
 stop2.setAttribute('stop-color', '#ff0')

linearGradient.appendChild(stop1)
linearGradient.appendChild(stop2)

 document.querySelector('svg defs').appendChild(linearGradient)
```

```html
<svg id="a663773f-8c77-4356-b99a-00f824054fe3" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 894.23 805.64">
  <defs>

    <radialGradient id="e87c7fc2-e4ed-4d65-889f-d6153929018e" cx="659.66" cy="541.62" r="261.56" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="#615ab2"/>
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#c0bde0"/>
    </radialGradient>
    <linearGradient id="a0a8f98c-a36f-4841-bfb8-51385632467d" x1="23.64" y1="496.01" x2="632.48" y2="496.01" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="#fff"/>
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#96e700"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <title>shapes</title>
  <g>
    <rect x="212.97" y="11" width="529.92" height="529.92" style="fill: url(#my-gradient)"/>
    <path d="M769.89,99V606.92H262V99H769.89m22-22H240V628.92H791.89V77Z" transform="translate(-38 -76.99)"/>
  </g>
  <g>
    <path d="M659.66,803.19a261.58,261.58,0,1,1,185-76.61A259.86,259.86,0,0,1,659.66,803.19Z" transform="translate(-38 -76.99)" style="fill: url(#e87c7fc2-e4ed-4d65-889f-d6153929018e)"/>
    <path d="M659.66,291.06a249.68,249.68,0,1,1-97.52,19.68,249,249,0,0,1,97.52-19.68m0-22c-150.53,0-272.56,122-272.56,272.56s122,272.57,272.56,272.57,272.57-122,272.57-272.57-122-272.56-272.57-272.56Z" transform="translate(-38 -76.99)"/>
  </g>
  <g>
    <polygon points="175.85 576.03 23.64 427.66 233.99 397.1 328.06 206.49 422.13 397.1 632.48 427.66 480.27 576.03 516.2 785.53 328.06 686.62 139.92 785.53 175.85 576.03" style="fill: url(#a0a8f98c-a36f-4841-bfb8-51385632467d)"/>
    <path d="M366.06,308.34l81.65,165.43,5.11,10.37,11.45,1.67,182.57,26.52L514.73,641.11l-8.28,8.07,1.95,11.4,31.19,181.83L376.3,756.56l-10.24-5.38-10.24,5.38L192.53,842.41l31.18-181.83,2-11.4-8.28-8.07L85.28,512.33l182.57-26.52,11.44-1.67,5.12-10.37,81.65-165.43m0-49.71L264.68,464,38,497,202,656.86,163.31,882.63,366.06,776,568.81,882.63,530.09,656.86,694.12,497,467.43,464,366.06,258.63Z" transform="translate(-38 -76.99)"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think

```
document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'linearGradient')
```

should work, according to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElementNS)